# Java - 8 : dynamic method arguments

Tags: java, java-8

This is the groovy code I am having:

```
def add(a, b) {
  return a+b
}

println add(1,2) // prints 3

println add("Suganthan","Madhavan")​ // prints SuganthanMadhavan
```

Where the groovy identifies the method argument on run. Would this runtime method argument detection is possible in `Java-8`?

Is that atleast possible through [MethodHandle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html) ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to understand, does java-8 support dynamic method argument detection

Comment: all you can do is write your custom overloaded methods to achieve this kind of behavior, that will be automatically detected by java that which method to call based on the type of argument

Comment: Java 8 adds some new _type inference_ -- where the compiler can infer types for you at compile time -- but this does not change the fundamental that Java is statically typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Groovy is a dynamically compiled language. Java is a statically compiled language.

Comment: Is that atleast possible through `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
` ?

Comment: No; a method will have particular types of argument. Statically compiled. Of course you can write `Object a, Object b` as arguments and then figure out what the objects are through reflection and then dynamically invoke the right concat function, but then you would be much better of just using Groovy. Groovy does something similar.

Comment: When u say, we can do it thru `reflection` I hope we can try that using `MethodHandle` too which might give much better in performance. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Suganthan: `MethodHandle`s can only be a small part of the solution. And the solution will turn out as something along the way of reimplementing Groovy...